# Trouble understanding solution for trig problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a problem that I am supposed to solve that is as:

Solve the trig equation $2\cos\theta + \sqrt{3} = 0$

Eventually it gets to $\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$

What I would like to know is how pi over 6 was arrived at. I imagine my teacher will want me to represent everything as algebraically as possible, so I think it's important to understand.

Here is a screenshot of the full problem:

[image: The equation in my assignment]

Comment: Start with an equilateral triangle of side $2$, draw a line from a vertex to a midpoint of a side. Your $\pi/6$ and its cosine come from there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is an equilateral triangle of side 2?

Comment: It is an equilateral triangle all of whose sides have length $2$.

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand. I suppose I am not familiar with that principle.

Comment: I assume you know we are working in radians, so $\pi/6$ is what in degrees is called $30^\circ$. Draw an equilateral triangle of side $2$.  Call it $ABC$. Draw a line from $A$ to the midpoint $M$ of $BC$. Look at triangle $AMC$, which is right-angled at $M$. Note that by the Pythagorean Theorem we have $AM=\sqrt{3}$. So the cosine of the $30^\circ$ angle $MAC$ is $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: Okay, this all makes sense to me now except why we are assuming $AM=\sqrt{3}$ . Why is it that according to Pythagorean Theorem that is so?

Comment: The hypotenus $AC$ is equal to $2$, and $MC$ is equal to $1$, since it is half of $BC$. Thus $AM^2=AC^2-MC^2=4-1=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $$\cos\left(\dfrac\pi6\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2,$$ then it follows that $$\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2\right)=\dfrac\pi6.$$

Comment: Ah, so maybe I should be referencing some sort of chart of values? I guess this is just simply understood?

Comment: @byteofthat Or just do exactly as I did.